Bedeutungen von "zusetzen"
Zum Verb zusetzen listet Duden 6 Bedeutungen auf:

zu einem Stoff hinzufügen und damit vermischen, verschmelzen o. Ä. Beispiele: [zu] dem Wein Wasser zusetzen | dem Silber Kupfer zusetzen. Die Hauptbedeutung, deren Verwendbarkeit außer Frage steht. Übrigens, ist es wahr, dass man die Präposition "zu" nur im Falle eines Getränkes hinzufügt?
(Geld) für etwas aufwenden und vom eigenen Kapital verlieren. Beispiele: viel Geld zusetzen | du hast nichts zuzusetzen (hast keine Kraftreserven). Habe ich weder auf context.reverso.net noch unter den ersten 150 Treffern in Gegenwartskorpora gesehen. Trotzdem haben beide Duden und DWDS dem Ausdruck du hast nichts zuzusetzen sogar eigene Abschnitte gewidmet.
jemanden hartnäckig zu etwas zu bewegen, zu überreden suchen; jemanden in lästiger Weise bedrängen. Beispiele: jemandem mit Bitten zusetzen | sie hat ihm so lange zugesetzt, bis er es getan hat. Context Reverso zeigt gar kein Anzeichen für so etwas, in den Korpora habe ich in 1-2 Treffern gesehen.
auf jemanden mit Heftigkeit eindringen [und ihn dabei verletzen]. Beispiel: jemandem mit dem Nudelholz zusetzen. ChatGPT Premium meint, sie sei schon veraltet, aber in den Korpora habe ich relativ viele Sätze gesehen wie Ali gelang es in den letzten beiden Runden, dem müde gewordenen Norton mit gezielten Rechts-links-Kombinationen zuzusetzen. Wie verbreitet sie in der Tat ist, kann ich jedoch nur annehmen.
sich auf jemandes physischen oder psychischen Zustand in unangenehmer, negativer Weise auswirken. Beispiel: die Krankheit hat ihm sehr zugesetzt. Ist auch offensichtlich im aktiven Gebrauch.
(reflexiv) durch Schmutz, Ablagerungen o. Ä. verschlossen werden. Beispiel: die Düse hatte sich zugesetzt. Keine Treffer in den Korpora, aber das ist wahrscheinlich auf die Bedeutung selber zurückzuführen; Context Reverso gibt allerdings viele an.

Das Interessante ist auch, dass die Definition, die vielen als erste einfällt - blockieren, buchstäblich zu|setzen - dort nur mit dem Reflexivpronomen vorhanden ist, obwohl sie in mehreren Beispielen von Context Reverso und auch in den Korpora vorkommt. Vielleicht ist sie einfach 'zu offensichtlich', aber ich habe noch nie gesehen, dass ein Wörterbuch den wörtlichen Sinn eines Wortes ignoriert (und DWDS erwähnt sogar die 6. Bedeutung nicht).
Also, ich würde gerne von Muttersprachlern etwas zu Bedeutungen 2-4 hören. Werden diese im Alltag noch verwendet? Und wenn jemand Informationen, auch aus eigener Erfahrung, über ihre Verwendung in Norddeutchland hat, würde ich mich sehr darüber freuen.

Nach meiner Erfahrung ist die Verwendung von zusetzen in allen genannten Bedeutungen so wie in den Beispielen gezeigt in Norddeutschland üblich.

Danke! Und "zusetzen" im Sinne von "verstopfen/blockieren" und ohne Reflexivpronomen ist auch gänglich?

Ich kenne nur die reflexive Variante.

Der "wörtliche" Sinn eines Ausdrucks ist meistens nur eine begrenzte Zeit wörtlich, dann fegt der Sprachwandel ihn hinweg. Bei der Mehrzahl der Einträge im Lexikon könntest Du feststellen, dass die "wörtliche" Bedeutung noch viel weniger prominent ist, wenn du nur weit genug in der Entwicklung zurückschaust.

Das macht Sinn, jedoch begegne ich ihr schon in den neusten Korporaeinträgen (beide davon sind Zitate aus Wikipedia): "Sie besaß eine zentrale Öffnung, die später durch Mauerwerk zugesetzt wurde", "Das ehemalige Südportal ist zugesetzt".

Ich kenne alle die Bedeutungen, und für mich sind auch alle mehr oder weniger gängig.
"zusetzen" im Sinne von "verstopfen" kenne ich aber tatsächlich nur reflexiv.

Interessant, danke! Und dieses "du hast nichts zuzusetzen" wird auch verwendet?

Selten, aber ja. Dabei muss dir klar sein, dass Bedeutung 1 und 2 m.A. nach eigentlich dieselbe sind. Ob man jetzt Backpulver dem Teig zusetzt oder Kraft und Geld einem Projekt, ist eigentlich kein großer Unterschied

Habe ich es dann falsch verstanden, dass, wenn man irgendwo Geld zusetzt, man da nichts gewinnt? So sagt DWDS: "(umgangssprachlich) aus etw. keinen Gewinn ziehen und stattdessen zusätzlich Geld investieren".

@aldin Nun, ob ich einem Projekt kein Geld/Aufwand/Kraft mehr zusetzen kann oder einem Kuchen kein Backpulver - beides wird wohl kein Erfolg werden....

"Kalk kann die Wasserleitungen zusetzen"?

@aldin: Geld zusetzen bedeutet Geld nachschießen, nachdem man also vorher schon Geld hineingesteckt hat. Ob nach dem zusetzen ein Erfolg eintritt oder nicht ist nicht gesagt - dieser soll sich ja erst in der Zukunft realisieren. In den meisten Fällen würden Investoren ja nichts nachschießen, wenn schon klar wäre, dass auch dieses Geld den Erfolg nicht bringt. Es gibt aber auch Rechtsformen, bei denen die Investoren gezwungen sind Geld nachzuschießen, ein Beispiel/Details habe ich aber leider nicht im Kopf.


2 ist einfach deshalb selten, weil die beschriebene Situation selten in Gesprächen vorkommt. Ich kenne sie aber, und ich bin kein Fachmann.
3 ist üblich
4 ist üblich, gerade in einem Sportzusammenhang


Danke für den Beitrag!

Die Bedeutung von "zusetzen" als "nichts weiteres hinzufügen können" wird insbesondere im Sport benutzt, wenn Sportler ermüdet sind
und keine Ausdauerreserven mehr haben. Beispiele: "Da hatten die Schalker nichts mehr zuzusetzen" oder "Da konnte Harrie nichts mehr zusetzen."

Ich denke, dem Eindruck, dass (6) die wörtliche Bedeutung sein sollte, liegt ein Missverständnis zugrunde. Das wäre der Fall, wenn "geschlossen" die primäre Bedeutung von "zu" wäre, was aber nicht so ist. DWDS listet diese Bedeutung sogar nur als umgangssprachlich.
Die Bedeutung "hinzufügen" wie in (1,2) kann hingegen als wörtliche Bedeutung betrachtet werden. Ob ich "zusetzen" aktiv in dieser Bedeutung benutze, weiß ich nicht. Ohne Kochrezepte zu schreiben oder Chemiker zu sein, habe ich wenig Anlass dazu.
Die Bedeutung (3,4,5) ist mir sehr geläufig, besonders in der Form (5).
Was (6) angeht, finde ich es verständlich, aber ich könnte nicht sagen, ob mir das Wort in dieser Bedeutung schon untergekommen ist.

Zusetzen im Sinne von "verstopfen" kenne ich aus dem (chemischen) Laborjargon sowohl reflexiv wie auch nichtreflexiv:

Wenn man zu kalt filtriert, dann kann (sich) der Filter zusetzen.

Meiner Erfahrung nach ist beides im Gebrauch, aber das ist Hörensagen und keine belastbare Quelle.
Die anderen Bedeutungen sind alle gebräuchlich.
Das Problem mit dwds.de und ähnlichen Sammlungen (zB. von Google) ist halt, daß sie erstens gesprochenes Deutsch ignorieren (obwohl das eine wesentliche Antriebskraft der Sprachentwicklung ist) und zweitens praktisch keine Umgangssprache enthalten. Auch die Auswahl der aufgenommenen Quellen folgt keinem Muster.
Bei Google kommt noch erschwerend hinzu, daß die wild Bücher eingescannt und per OCR digitalisiert haben, was gerade bei Fraktur oftmals zu Fehlern führt, die aber mangels jeder Form von Qualitätskontrolle - Masse statt Klasse - nicht ausgemerzt werden.
Profis - so sagt zumindest Daniel Scholten - verwenden solche Quellen nicht.

Vielen Dank! Ja, da ist der Mangel an gesprochener Sprache spürbar. Deswegen verlasse ich mich fast gar nicht darauf, wenn es um entsprechende Bedeutungen geht, und frage einfach hier oder meine Bekannten irl, die - vielleicht - bereit wären, mir solche Sachen zu erläutern.
